# Neo4j Cypher sort on collections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query (below) that returns collections of nodes containing create dates. I want to sort the rows by newest create date. Some of the rows have one create date, other rows have several. As can be seen, the node "name4" should be first. What corrections should I make to my query?  Thanks.

```
MATCH (node:node) 
WITH node 
ORDER BY node.created DESC 
RETURN count(node.name) AS count, node.name, collect(node.created) AS created

count   node.name   created
3       "name1"     [1410234609620,1410234606534,1410234506799]
1       "name2"     [1410234434936]
1       "name3"     [1410234454573]
2       "name4"     [1410463902552,1410460561481]
1       "name5"     [1410234485185]
2       "name6"     [1410234548527,1410234525740]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your timestamps are correctly ordered within your collections, you can take the first timestamp from each of the collections using `HEAD([1, 2, 3])`, which will return the first element of the collection. I've loaded this value into the `timeSort` property and used it as the ordering criteria.

```
MATCH (node:node) 
WITH node
ORDER BY node.created DESC 
WITH count(node.name) AS count, node.name as name, collect(node.created) AS created
WITH count, name, head(created) as timeSort, created
RETURN count, name, created
ORDER BY timeSort DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

This query first finds the max timestamp, `x`, for each name, and then sorts the results.

```
MATCH (node:node)
WITH node.name AS name, COLLECT(node.created) AS created
WITH name, created, REDUCE(t = 0, c IN created | CASE WHEN c > t THEN c ELSE t END) AS x
RETURN LENGTH(created) AS count, name, created
ORDER BY x DESC
```

Comment: This also works. Though, for what it's worth, Kenny's is easier to read.