# Neo4j Cypher sort on unordered collections

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to do something very similar to the user in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796226/neo4j-cypher-sort-on-collections%20this%20question), that is sort the results on the elements in a collection. However, unlike the use case in that question, my collection is unsorted.

So to use the example from that question:

````
```MATCH (node:node) - [:has] -> (scores) 
WITH node 
ORDER BY node.created DESC 
RETURN count(node.name) AS count, node.name, collect(node.created) AS created

count   node.name   created
3       "name1"     [1410234609620,1410234606534,1410234506799]
1       "name2"     [1410234434936]
1       "name3"     [1410234454573]
2       "name4"     [1410463902552,1410460561481]
1       "name5"     [1410234485185]
2       "name6"     [1410234548527,1410234525740]
```
````

The accepted answer was:

```
MATCH (node:node) 
WITH node
ORDER BY node.created DESC 
WITH count(node.name) AS count, node.name as name,   collect(node.created) AS created
WITH count, name, head(created) as timeSort, created
RETURN count, name, created
ORDER BY timeSort DESC
```

Getting head(created) returns the correct result when the collection is already sorted. Mine is not. Is there a way to sort that collection before calling head?

Answer (score 1):

To sort a collection you can use UNWIND + ORDER BY

```
UNWIND coll as x
WITH x ORDER BY x.foo
RETURN collect(x);
```

Comment: I don't think unwinding is what I need, since in the code above it is possible to run ORDER BY before collecting. In the code, node.created returns an list of timestamps. I need to sort those times, so I can get the most recent, and then I want to order the nodes by the head of that list.

Comment: You need to UNWIND your collection if you want to sort it. Or sort your data before collecting.